# I can't accept or dismiss alert in a new window - selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, alert

I've been struggling with a problem in a webscraping project.

At some point, I need to click on an element that opens a new window.

First thing that appears in the new window is an alert. I tried to accept it, but nothing happens. The page only keeps loading, but it doesn't accept the alert and it doesn't raise an error.

Here's my code:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, name of the element).click()
time.sleep(2)

#Switching to New Window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(2)

#Accepting alert
alert = Alert(driver)
alert.accept()
```

How can I accept/dismiss this alert?

Comment: Post the url you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Well, I can't share the url, because it's the company's system that I work for haha There's a privacy politics involved. But I can share screenshots. Will it help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be really difficult for anyone to help you, without access to the actual url.

Comment: Is there any chance to have a meeting in Google Meets, so I show you the web system and the RPA that I'm developing? I'm sure it'll be easy for you to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry, no. My advice to you is to debug the issue, step by step: try to dismiss the alert manually while watching the Network tab, see what calls are made. Then do it step by step with selenium (don't use headless option). I'm sure you will figure it out.

Comment: It seems it's workinga now haha It seems that the problem was the time.sleep(). I removed it from the code and now it's acceptting the alert! Idk if makes sense, but it's working haha

Comment: Glad you worked it out.